# Save result from dropdown list to another table

Tags: php, database

I have two tables in my database. I have a form to add information to table `news`. In my form I have dropdown list with information from another table `courses`. I want to save the result of the selection and save it in table `news`. How I can do that?

**code:**

```
<p>Course</p>
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("university");
$sql = "SELECT name FROM courses";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
print '<select>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
   print '<option value='.$row['name'].'>'.$row['name'].'</option>';       
 }  
print '</select>';
?>
```

Comment: Where is the form, filed name/id etc??

Comment: Are you asking how to perform an `INSERT` query on the database?  How to get form values from `$_POST`?  It's not really clear where you're stuck.

Comment: noo, i dont know how to save the result of this selection. I mean i think i need to save it in a variable.

Comment: my method is POST. I already saved information with dropdown list, but in this list problem is that im using nother table so im confused

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to give a `name`attribute to your `select` tag, then as soon as you post your form, you will get the value of the selected `option` the exact same way as you get the value of other input fields.

I would also advise to get both the id and the name of your courses from your selct query. You should then use the id as the `value` attribute of your `option` , qhile you can keep the name to display it to the user. That way you would store the id of the selected course instead of the name, meaning that if a name slightly changes, you will still have the proper course id stored.

So your final HTML for this field should look something like that :

```
<select name="selectedcourse">
    <option value="1">Course 1</option>
    <option value="2">Course 2</option>
    <option value="3">Course 3</option>
</select>
```

And you would get the seleted value server-side in PHP using something like :

```
$_POST["selectedcourse"]
```

If, of course, your form method was POST and not GET...